# How to understand CurrentCell is in edit mode or not in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am creating custom `DataGrid`. When i press the keyboard i want to learn `CurrentCell` is in edit mode or not. I know how to handle `KeyDown` event. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279502/how-to-determine-whether-a-wpf-datagrid-is-in-edit-mode) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248023/code-to-check-if-a-cell-of-a-datagrid-is-currently-edited) post. The solutions there didn't help solve my problem. I couldn't find a better way to find out if `CurrentCell` is in edit mode or not. How can i achieve this? Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why both of the linked solutions do not solve your problem?

Comment: I'm working on a DataGrid of thousands of rows. The solutions there have extra control structures, and some have loops. So when I run the application, checking that one of the cells is in edit mode or not is like a death trap. I needed a better solution that I couldn't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the `BeginningEdit` and `CellEditEnding` and use a variable to keep track of the currently edited cell:

```
private DataGridCellInfo _editedCell;

private void DataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
{
    _editedCell = dataGrid.CurrentCell;
}

private void DataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    _editedCell = default(DataGridCellInfo);
}
```

You can then use the variable to check whether the cell is currently in edit mode:

```
if (dataGrid.CurrentCell == _editedCell)
...
```