# WPF DataGrid - How to show a button in a row when the row is editing (detect edit mode)?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to show a cancel button, when row is in edit mode.

[image: Editing DataGrid row containing a cancel changes button]
[source code](https://gist.github.com/marbel82/38435f3cd8a8a3b9e373a1e62d901f2b)

I can't find what I should bind to.

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
...
    <Button Content="✖" Visibility="{Binding ????}" />
```

I find that we can implement additional markup extension,
[SO: "Code to check if a cell of a DataGrid is currently edited"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248345/2122718),
but is there, a simplest solution?

Comment: Also you can set visibility of something based on a trigger. If the `textBox` has focus, do X.

Comment: Please mark a given answer as accepted if it helped solving your problem. If none of the given answers helped, please further clarrify your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```xml
<Button Content="✖" Visibility="{Binding IsEditing, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
    Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

Just look at *Live Visual Tree*. By RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor you can move up to find `DataGridRow`, and this one contains `IsEditing` property.

[image]

Comment: I had answered the same thing i guess. What is the change here?

Comment: Which cell should I bind to if I have 3 in a row. I have to bind to DataGridRow not DataGridCell. My question is "...show button when row is editing"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the [CellTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate) use the [CellEditingTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celleditingtemplate)

See the following description for the `CellEditingTemplate`:

> The template that is used to display the contents of a cell that is in editing mode. The registered default is null. For information about what can influence the value, see

Comment: Thanks, CellEditingTemplate would be ok, if I wanted to do cell cancellation. I would prefer RowEditingTemplate if it existed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IsEditing` property of `DataGridCell` to know if the cell in is edit mode. Bind this property to the `Visibility` of the button.